# DST issue in protovis

Tags: javascript, dst, protovis

I am using the render() method in the protovis(http://mbostock.github.io/protovis/) library to render a histogram. A couple of weeks ago, when Day light savings kicked in, while rendering histograms on "either" side of the time that DST begain(2 AM on March 13), it looks like the render method was stuck in an infinite loop and my code went oom.

Has anyone seen something like this before? Any tips/suggestions on how I could tackle something like this?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you ignoring the notice the creators put on the library?

Comment: @Daedalus Same code has been used for my company for past 5-6 years. Will look to rewrite it with using some newer library if I am unable to figure this out.